# Distance from earth to heaven

Tags: earth, swarga

We are living in the earth and there exists heaven (Swarga) according to the Hinduism.

How much is the distance from the earth to heaven according to the Hindu scriptures?

Comment: Indraloka is swarga and is distanced  1 lakh yojana =(8 lakha km) (Vishnu purana 2.7.5).

Comment: Source (page 134, 135): http://vedicilluminations.com/downloads/Puranas/Visnu%20Purana/Vishnupurana-English-MnDutt_text.pdf

Comment: @Wikash_ Why are you answering in comments?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda Many visited heaven before death; Ravana, Arjuna etc. are examples..and Yudhisthira went to heaven with his body...